# Methods to study reaction mechanisms in solid state reactions and identifying intermediates

Tags: computational-chemistry, ab-initio-calculations, reaction-mechanism

An example of a solid state reaction: sintering of an initial powder of reactants leading to a product. Densification of the sintered powder giving a highly pure product powder.

What methods (*ab initio* or otherwise) would one use to study the reaction mechanism involved, possible reaction pathways, and identify intermediates?

Comment: This seems fairly broad at the moment. Some possible avenues for narrowing it down: 1. Are you more interested in the electronic structure side or the molecular dynamics? 2. Are you interested in more qualitative methods (e.g. searches for new reaction pathways) or quantitative (e.g. attempts to characterize a known pathway). 3. Are you interested in applying this to a specific type of physical system (e.g. materials, molecules, metals, liquids, enzymes, etc)? 4. Are you just interested in how/why nudged elastic band is used?

Comment: Thank you, Tyberius. Do you think the edit about solid state reactions narrows the scope down adequately?

Comment: I think the edit makes the question clearer and gives more context that an answerer can work with. Thanks for taking the time to edit!

Comment: I don't have time to make a longer comment, but you may find [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-021-23339-x) of interest to you.

Comment: Hitanshu, was that paper suggested by Andrew helpful?

Comment: This question has been closed as it seems to be abandoned. It can be reopened if someone wants to add an answer or the OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments.